# Обрезать картинку с камеры

Tags: android, камера

У меня есть SurfaceView, который отображает камеру для считывания баркодов. Мне нужна только нижняя четверть изображения с камеры.

```
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Я задаю его размер, вся картинка с камеры сжимается под эти размеры.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels / 4);
        cameraView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Вот инициализация камеры. Пытался задавать размеры через `setRequestedPreviewSize`, но это не помогает.

```
    final BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector =
            new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
                    .build();

    final CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource
            .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels / 4)
            .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
            .build();
```

Делал по этому руководству: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reading-qr-codes-using-the-mobile-vision-api--cms-24680

Как можно обрезать картинку с камеры? Нужна только нижняя четверть.